# How do I display summary calculations in the footer of a PrimeNG table?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I'm having a heck of a time finding out how to do a simple summary function at the end of a PrimeNG `p-table`.  For example, if I want to total a particular column in the last row of the table, or display the minimum of a value of integers, or any other summary operation like that — for whatever rows are visible in the table at the time.

I've tried rolling my own by accessing PrimeNG's `Table` object itself in the component:

`@ViewChild('dt', { static: true }) private dt: Table;`

And then looking at the contents of that via

`console.table(this.dt)`

I can access the `filteredValue` property of `this.dt` once I've typed something into any of the column filters.  But I can't access what's in `this.dt.value` or `this.dt._value`.  PrimeNG's documentation makes mention of a "Summary section" but gives no guidance on how to perform summary functions in that section:

[PrimeNG documentation for Table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table)

Perplexed.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use the "Summary" functionality but rather the "footer" template.

Something like that:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="footer">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td>Total:$506,202</td>
        <td>Min:$8,500</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefooter?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Well, the values you're showing in there are hard-coded.  And what you're showing comes straight from the documentation, which I'd already read and seen that their example shows hard-coded values. In the snippet you've provided, I would need the Total and Min values to be dynamically calculated based on what's visible in the table.

Comment: You just have to replace hard coded values with functions that return what you need.

Comment: In the stackblitz demo, it appears the error ---> Error in turbo_modules/primeng@9.1.0/resources/primeng.min.css
Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/dev/null'